# FileLoadException from netstandard.dll in installed version but not in debug

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

We ported our base libraries to netstandard2.0 and consume them in an wpf net461 application. While debugging in visual studio everthing works fine.

But when using the release version installed via setup we get an fileloadexception.

FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)'

I verified that the setup installed everthing needed and that the binding redirects are corret. But still i get the exception.

Comment: clean and re-build? that's always helping... :-)

Comment: Version 0.0 is going to be awfully hard to find.  Showing us the fuslogvw.exe trace is pretty essential.  And you need to show us the binding redirects in the .config file as well as any AssemblyResolve event handler in your code.

Comment: I tried to use fusion log but it only showed one error. For an ViewModel.XmlSerializers.dll File that could not be loaded.

How can i use the AssemblyResolve event to debug this error?

Comment: Here is a link to what my config file is looking like. I am using AutoGenerateBindingRedirects.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ang7y1vij6q58d3/wpf.exe.config?dl=0